# Button not doing anything on click. How come?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
echo "<tr><td colspan ='2'><center><input type='submit' value='Reply' onClick = "window.open = 'post_reply.php?cid=".$cid." &tid =".$tid."' /">";
```

Button does nothing.Can someone help fix.

Comment: Your only code is `echo "";`. There is no button.

Comment: please add more context, that is not enough information

Comment: It wont display whats in quotes even though its there when I edit.

Comment: I've edited the post, the syntax highlighting may make the issue apparent now.

Comment: To avoid escaping issues, and make everything much cleaner, just close the PHP tags and write plain HTML and re-open PHP tags when you need dynamic content. The duplicate I linked shows different techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings are quoted wrong, your second double quote after on click = terminates the string, I havent tested my soloution but you need something like (below)

You need to escape double qoutes if it is literally part of the string

```
echo "<tr><td colspan ='2'><center><input type='submit' value='Reply' onClick='window.open(\"post_reply.php?cid=$cid&tid=$tid\")' />";
```